# How do I remove sites from the search results

Tags: search, search-scope

I am trying to clean up my SharePoint search results.  Alongside .aspx pages, the search is also returning sites (e.g. http://mywebsite/news), even when these site names have no similarities to the search query string.  The sites in the results are always given the thumbnail _layouts/images/STS_ListItem16.gif.

So to fix this I have tried to create a new search scope.  The problem I am having is that most of the basic contentclass rules are returning no items.  http://www.rtsmedia.com/SharePoint/contentclass.aspx and other pages have pointed me in the right direction, but of the properties I have tried, only STS_ListItem_850 and STS_List_850 are returning any items.

Other basic properties that you would imagine would work (STS_List_WebPageLibrary, STS_ListItem_WebPageLibrar, STS_Web) all return 0 items (in the itemcount column on the scope details page).

Comment: it's hard to say how to optimize your results without knowing what data you have on sites and want to receive from search. Please specify more detailed.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure every web to avoid that appears in search results. This option is "*Site Actions > Site Configuration > Site Administration > Search Availability and offline*". Check to not "*Index site content*" and do an incremental crawl.

Sorry if the path has not the exactly options but my SharePoint is in Spanish and I've done a quick translation.

/EN SharePoint 2013 Site Settings > Search > Search and offline availability

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up using file extension managed property and removing images. But optimization depends on the nature of result you what to receive.

Comment: Thanks default - currently the OOTB search is returning sites, pages and documents.  I am trying to remove the sites from the results, everything else is fine.  The sites that are returned do not match the search query (I imagine they appeare because pages inside of them match the search query).

Comment: Apologies if I didn't make myself clear.  I want the pages that appear in /news to appear in the search results, I just don't want the /news 'web' itself to appear as is currently happening.

Comment: See this link how to exclude particular page from results - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621095.aspx

Comment: Also you can check Crawl Rules to exclude or include items from searched